# Jacobian to do Newton's method.

Tags: matrices, jacobian

[PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4RPX.png)I want to do a Newton's iteration using Jacobian and I did not understand how to do that. Can someone explain the steps to me please?

[SOLUTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0wSN.jpg)

Comment: Can you post more details and where you stuck?

Comment: @user251257 I added a picture. I do not know how to find J. I have the solutions but i didn't understand then. So i wanted to know if someone can tell me the steps..

Comment: do you know how to compute derivatives?

Comment: @user251257 yes

Comment: just compute the 4 partial derivatives and write them down as the Jacobian $J$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,
you have a system of two equations, namely 
\begin{split}
f_1(x_1,x_1) = 0\\ f_2(x_1,x_2) = 0
\end{split}

The Newton method reads
$$\left[\begin{array}{c} x_1\\ x_2\end{array}\right]^{n+1} = \left[\begin{array}{c} x_1\\ x_2\end{array}\right]^{n} - \left(J^{-1}\right)^{n}\left[\begin{array}{c} f_1(x_1,x_2)\\ f_2(x_1,x_2)\end{array}\right]^n \tag1$$
Where $J^{-1}$ is the inverse of the Jacobian, that is
$$J=\left[\begin{array}{cc} 
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2} \\ \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2}\end{array}\right]
$$
Use the equation $(1)$ recursively, starting with $n=0$ with your initial guess
$$\left[\begin{array}{c} x_1\\ x_2\end{array}\right]^{0}=\left[\begin{array}{c} 1\\ 1\end{array}\right]$$

Comment: I just posted the solutions i have. I don't understand why they do not use J inverse for the first step

Comment: Okay, it is the same. For sure you calculate the "inverse" of $J$, solving $\vec{v}$ from 
$$J^{n}\vec{v}=\vec{f}^{n}\tag2$$
and later you update your solution with 
$$\vec{v} = \vec{x}^{n+1}-\vec{x}^{n}\tag3$$
You will also notice that the equation $(1)$ I wrote is formally the same as $(2)$ with $(3)$

Comment: I don't understand what v is .

Comment: $\vec{v}$ is defined on your homework. The procedure you follow in your solution is first solve $\vec{v}$ from the system in $(2)$ and update your solution by using $(3)$. Do you understand it know?

Comment: no .. :/ i still dont know how to replace the values or understand what is going on

Comment: Follow these steps loking at the same time to your solution please:
$$\quad$$
1. Compute the Jacobian $J$. It must be a function of $x_1$ and $x_2$. $$\quad$$
2. Substitute in the Jacobian $J(x_1,x_2)$ and function $\vec{f}(x_1,x_2)$ the values of $x_1$ and $x_2$ from the seed you are provided $(1,1)$.
$$\quad$$
3. Once computed, solve the system $J\vec{v}=\vec{f}$ for the computed $J$ and $\vec{f}$. 
$$\quad$$
4. Now you know the value of $\vec{v}$. The next solution for $x_1$ and $x_2$ you will obtain is $\vec{x}^{n+1}=\vec{v}+(x_1,x_2)^{T}
$$\quad$$

Comment: Repeat the procedure from 1, this time with the initial solution of $\vec{x}^{n+1}$ instead of $(1,1)$

Comment: OMG IT IS SO EASY. I CAN'T BELIEVE I DIDNT UNDERSTAND THAT